# Module to convert a decimal amount of US Dollars to an equivalent amount of BitCoin

Tags: 7

I am still new to Drupal and am looking for a module that does the following: convert a decimal amount of US Dollars to an equivalent amount of Bitcoin.

Is there such a module that can handle this or would I have to code this from scratch?

More info:

1. Accepts a decimal based argument in USD
2. Submitting the form sends a request to a 3rd party API to convert the dollar amount to BitCoin
3. Module should create a means to store any API connection details required to communicate with your API key in the database
4. Module should pull this value from the database when making a request to the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for the [UC Bitcoin](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_bitcoin) module

> This module provides an alternative 'payment gateway' that enables your clients to pay in the equivalent amount in BTC (Bitcoin currency)
>
> It does this by doing a current market exchange rate lookup of your stores default currency and then allowing an option to let people pay in the equivalent BTC amount.

Comment: If I were to code this from scratch are there any guides on how to do this?

Comment: Search for "Drupal module developers guide" for the Drupal part - connecting to an Api and downloading currency data will just be plain old php, however you want to attack that will be fine. The Bitcoin module will probably be the best place to look for inspiration, as it already does what you need. If you're stuck with specific implementation details to do with the Drupal part of it, just ask new questions about those.